# Is there a easy way to split a large CSV file with multiline entries?

Tags: csv, split, large-files

Hi i have this huge 14Gb CSV file with entries that span multiple lines and would like a easy way to split it, BTW the split command will not work cause it is not aware of how many columns there are on a row and will cut it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XSV (https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) is very simple:

```
xsv split -s 10000 ./outputdir inputFile.csv
```

`-s 10000` to set the number of records to write into each chunk.

Comment: Amazing man, exactly the kind of tool i was looking for, superb!

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking everywhere for this!

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_root = r"/home/glauber/Projetos/nlp/"
fname = r"blogset-br.csv.gz"
this_file = os.path.join(data_root,fname)
assert os.path.exists(this_file), this_file
this_file

column_names = ['postid', 'blogid', 'published', 'title', 'content', 'authorid', 'author_displayName', 'replies_totalItems', 'tags']
parse_dates = ['published']
df_iterator = pd.read_csv(this_file,
                          skiprows=0,
                          compression='gzip',
                          chunksize=1000000,
                          header=None,
                          names = column_names,
                          parse_dates=parse_dates,
                          index_col=1)

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
count = 0
for df in df_iterator:
    filename = 'blogset-br-' + str(count ) + '.csv'
    df.to_csv(filename)
    count += 1
```

this is the easiest way i could find